# when a form is set as topmost detecting desktop or other windows show?

Tags: c#

I have noticed however that a form that is set as Topmost does not actually stay
displayed when the show desktop button is pressed! 
I want to detect other form over the topmost event.

Comment: And what behavior do you want instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "doesn't" rather than "does"? It sounds like you want a form that always stays on top regardless of what the user or other app want.

If so, [it can't be done](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).